# Which ArrayBufferView

Tags: javascript, html, blob, filewriter, arraybuffer

I'm retrieving an ArrayBuffer over XHR and want to save it to the FileSystem API using a FileWriter. The FileWriter expects a Blob and the Blob constructor won't take an ArrayBuffer, it takes an ArrayBufferView.

There are many ArrayBufferViews to choose from, how do I know which is the correct to use?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

At [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray), you can find an overview of all available `ArrayBufferView` subclasses:

| Type | Bytes | Description | Equivalent C type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [`Int8Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Int8Array) | 1 | 8-bit twos complement signed integer | `int8_t` |
| [`Uint8Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array) | 1 | 8-bit unsigned integer | `uint8_t` |
| [`Uint8ClampedArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8ClampedArray) | 1 | 8-bit unsigned integer (clamped) | `uint8_t` |
| [`Int16Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Int16Array) | 2 | 16-bit twos complement signed integer | `int16_t` |
| [`Uint16Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint16Array) | 2 | 16-bit unsigned integer | `uint16_t` |
| [`Int32Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Int32Array) | 4 | 32-bit twos complement signed integer | `int32_t` |
| [`Uint32Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint32Array) | 4 | 32-bit unsigned integer | `uint32_t` |
| [`Float32Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Float32Array) | 4 | 32-bit IEEE floating point number | `float` |
| [`Float64Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Float64Array) | 8 | 64-bit IEEE floating point number | `double` |
| [`BigInt64Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt64Array) | 8 | 64-bit two's complement signed integer | `int64_t` |
| [`BigUint64Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigUint64Array) | 8 | 64-bit unsigned integer | `uint64_t` |

Basically, this lists what memory spaces each item of the array would occupy and if it's a plain number or a FP number. I'm not sure what languages you're familiar with, but if it also covers Java, then it is basically the same choice as you'd make on `byte[]`, `short[]`, `int[]`, `float[]` and `double[]` (Java is always signed, so that part doesn't matter).

We know, binary data like images is usually represented as a byte array. A short/int/long array can also, but this is a waste of memory space. If you would store a 100KB image (note that "B" stands for byte, which is 8 bits) in an int array instead of a byte array, then it would occupy 400KB of memory, which is a waste of 300KB. So the smallest one, `Int8Array`, would already suffice with regard to memory space. If you'd ever like to programmatically traverse it — which is very unlikely in this case — as an unsigned array, then you may opt for the `Uint8Array` instead where each item holds values `0` to `255` instead of values `-128` to `127`.

Here's a copy'n'paste'n'runnable kickoff example which downloads an image file from the server, saves it to the temporary local storage space and presents it as an `<img>` in the body (little jQuery is required for that part). This example assumes that the `image.png` file is located in the same base folder as the JS (or HTML, in case JS is inlined) file is been downloaded from:

```js
window.requestFileSystem = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 1024*1024, startDownload, errorHandler);

var errorHandler = function(error) {
    console.log('FS error: ' + error);
}

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'image.png', true);
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

function startDownload(fileSystem) {
    xhr.onload = function(event) {
        var content = new Int8Array(this.response);
        fileSystem.root.getFile('/image.png', { 'create': true }, function(fileEntry) {
            fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {
                fileWriter.onwriteend = function(event) {
                    $('body').append('<p>Image successfully downloaded:</p>')
                             .append('<p><img src="' + fileEntry.toURL() + '"/></p>');
                };

                var blob = new Blob([content], { type: 'image/png' });
                fileWriter.write(blob);
            }, errorHandler);
        });
    }

    xhr.send();
}
```

Note, as of the [current](https://caniuse.com/filesystem) state, this works in Chrome, Edge and Opera only and not (yet?) in Safari nor Firefox.